# Meeting Organizer Changes, Duplicate Attendees, Duplicate Meetings

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2007, blackberry, calendar

I have a user who is ending up with a lot of duplicate meetings, duplicate attendees, and/or the meeting organizer changes.  This seems to happen when users outside the company reply to the meeting in someone, or try to reschedule.  The most consistent thing I think is that the meeting organizer changes to the person who replies.

The Exchange Server is 2003, client is Outlook 2007, and the user has a Blackberry and we are running BES.

I am having trouble locking down the problem, currently, any conflict warnings have probably been deleted.  I ran scanpst.exe and that didn't find issues.  The BB for email is set to "Mailbox Wins", I didn't see a similar setting in outlook.

Anyone know of any server side tools I can look at to try to understand the problem, or seen similar problems?

Answer (score 1):

What version of BES are you using?  I know that the calendaring agent is missing in Exchange 2007 and must be added manually.  Incorrect versions can cause some superfunky behavior (technical term).  The solution there was to make sure that the CDO.dll file included on the BES server is the same version (or newer) than the version on the Exchange server.  Again, this was a situation I ran into with Exchange 2007, but I wouldn't be surprised if it was a similar issue for Exchange 2003.  I also remember seeing warnings in the application event log on the Exchange server (8206 and 8207 if I remember correctly).  I'd take a look in there and see if you don't see errors when the meetings are modified.

Edit:  I referenced a non-existent file earlier.  That may be part of your problem in locating it.  It is CDO.dll, not .sys.  Anyway, please reference this link since it seems to be much more detailed than I can offer.

Use this knowledge base article [KB-02937] from RIM to troubleshoot/verify your setup:

http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/articles/724/KB02937_f.SAL_Public.html

Comment: Where is that sys file located in both cases?

Comment: Go to the Exchsrvr\bin directory to check the version of the CDO.DLL file on your Microsoft Exchange Server.

Use the following document to help you figure out where your CDO.dll on the BES is located.  http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB04912  It can technically be any location, so you really need to follow these steps.